# Custom icons in expandable panel not working as expected in Vuetify 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

Problem statement **:** Custom `down` and `up` arrows icons are not working as expected on expand/collapse the panels manually.

Requirement **:** As Vuetify provides default arrows icons at the end on expandable-panel-title, I want to add those at the starting before panel title text. And I am able to successfully do that but the issue I am facing in changing the state of these icons on expand/collapse the panel.

[image]

This is how my component design for these expandable panels.

[image]

In above diagram, each child component (`ChildComponentA`/`ChildComponentB`/`ChildComponentC`) contains single `<v-expansion-panel>` that's the reason we can not use `v-loop` on `<v-expansion-panels>`. We are just passing the dynamic data for each  as a `prop` from parent component.

With default icons, it is working fine. Here is the playground [`link`](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

With custom icons, it is not working. Here is the playground [`link`](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNrtVE2PmzAQ/SsjLrRSHKTtRpUQ2XYrtcf+gSQHBxsF1dgWNjQV4r93jIkTCO2u1B735K/33ozfjGbXRabOk2et123DozTKLK+0oJY/7SVAxsp22Pgt5IIas91Hlp8tybm0vAZGCsHPoI/kcR+NYIS35GhlIFSUPOwj+JyLMv+BZyoEguHrWVPJ4FkIyJKB8VoBqSR3Ct9xnXGzxGe9kLc+kw3oX2SD1JZUinEBKXQdYBq47fsZtyXcZWhKJckAMTDSnJi7wJyqRthSC+/YMg1aKhqOnEKpG5OWoMSWVnAYbhkpcyWRNuEg61IkzMYIZVOaWxRwP+xGJmfQz1hDNCcI6SgboJ8gjtGIOEaKM9O9TyMmk76YC+JSoF5psJJYU+5EUapiJclPvK3xc41eFg4KaC6fMJj6KRc539DEq4OIWLTwBZexg5+c0lh6d17WcsBQ2XtAaJa/1v1I67e6/2vdv6CJ/6XuM9GbFnhB35EXHi6sMIDu54Yfp+N0mbiKR5PXpfZpIU/VFhgvKI4V6Lwio5a+e385AdTcNrW8nsF/IYXdYXW9m5QlhYKi0+G595t+vKi4PSlmcBheADiib0MC2FNp1hNN2IKtGz6DeDe3sItx2sUriLH540OIGzJwI/wVEYa0/xTiTtav+LksCa5G/Sr6sH5cf4zculk/RIffUv4lbg==).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first problem I see is that the up/down icon of each item inside the default slot of the title is rendered based on the current value of `isAllExpanded`, but it should be rendered based on current item's `expanded` value. You can access it inside the title by replacing

```html
<v-expansion-panel-title>
   ...default slot contents here
</v-expansion-panel-title>
```

...with:

```html
<v-expansion-panel-title>
  <template v-slot:default="{ expanded }">
     ...default slot contents here, with access to current item's expanded
  </template>
</v-expansion-panel-title>
```

2. Another problem is that you're keeping `isAllExpanded` in state. It should be a `computed` returning the computed value of whether or not any of the available panels is not contained in `this.panels`. This way you don't have to worry about setting it correctly. It's always going to be correct.
   [See it working here](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).
3. Last, but not least, you should keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), including the `<template />`. Rather than writing a separate `<v-expansion-panel>` for each panel, you should loop through them using a `v-for`:
   [Working example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I will check. But the reason why I can not loop `<v-expansion-panels>` as it does not have direct child `<v-expansion-panel>`, these single panel are under the seperate components as I mentioned in the screenshot. So if i will loop `<v-expansion-panels>` it will loop each child component multiple times which i dont want.

Comment: Loop through `<v-expansion-panel>` like in the example I provided, not through `<v-expansion-panels>`. If you provide a *runnable* [mcve] I'll make it DRY.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I was using `v-slot:actions` instead of `v-slot:default`, thats the reason I was not able to make the icon before title text after adding inside the slot template but with `default` it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

you never toggled your data `isAllExpended` in your code and your variable will always be false.

I added `@click` and toggled `isAllExpended` and it worked. like this:

```
<v-expansion-panels v-model="panel" multiple>
  <v-expansion-panel value="bar" @click="isAllExpended = !isAllExpended"> //here
    <v-expansion-panel-title expand-icon="">
      <template v-slot:actions="{ expanded }">
        <v-icon :icon="expanded ? '' : ''"></v-icon>
      </template>
      <v-icon v-show="isAllExpended">mdi-chevron-up</v-icon>
      <v-icon v-show="!isAllExpended">mdi-chevron-down</v-icon>
      Bar
    </v-expansion-panel-title>
    <v-expansion-panel-text>
      Bar panel text
    </v-expansion-panel-text></v-expansion-panel>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

EDIT: I created a snippets from vuetify [document](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/expansion-panels/#custom-icon) i hope this helps you.

```js
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify

const vuetify = createVuetify()
const App = {
  name: "App",
};

Vue.createApp(App).use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.4.7/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.5.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3.5.2/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <v-expansion-panels class="mb-6">
      <v-expansion-panel
        v-for="i in 3"
        :key="i"
      >
        <v-expansion-panel-title expand-icon="mdi-menu-down">
          Item
        </v-expansion-panel-title>
        <v-expansion-panel-text>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</v-expansion-panel-text>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>

    <v-expansion-panels>
      <v-expansion-panel>
        <v-expansion-panel-title expand-icon="mdi-plus" collapse-icon="mdi-minus">
          Item
        </v-expansion-panel-title>
        <v-expansion-panel-text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </v-expansion-panel-text>
      </v-expansion-panel>

      <v-expansion-panel>
        <v-expansion-panel-title>
          Item
          <template v-slot:actions="{ expanded }">
            <v-icon :color="!expanded ? 'teal' : ''" :icon="expanded ? 'mdi-pencil' : 'mdi-check'"></v-icon>
          </template>
        </v-expansion-panel-title>
        <v-expansion-panel-text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </v-expansion-panel-text>
      </v-expansion-panel>

      <v-expansion-panel>
        <v-expansion-panel-title disable-icon-rotate>
          Item
          <template v-slot:actions>
            <v-icon color="error" icon="mdi-alert-circle">
            </v-icon>
          </template>
        </v-expansion-panel-title>
        <v-expansion-panel-text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
        </v-expansion-panel-text>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-expansion-panels>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: ff]

Comment: This will not work as I am having multiple panels and as per your code we are updating the global variable from each panel which means on single collapse it will collapse all the panels and vice versa which is not my requirement.

Comment: If your panels are in a loop, you can define an array and handle it with your v-for key. isAllExpended:[] in your data, v-for="(item,index) in yourList" :key="index" and @click="isAllExpended[index] = !isAllExpended[index]"

Comment: I tried this way but I am confused how it will change the state of the icons. As you know everything is working fine. Only I am facing the challenges in icons state change on single expand/collapse. I updated the question with the component structure.

Comment: I created a snippets from vuetify document, i hope this helps you. Maybe it only recognizes "expanded" and you are using a different variable(isAllExpended) and it can't handle it with "v-slot:actions="{ expanded }".

Comment: I saw your snippet but it is working fine with the default arrow icons placeholder, But as I already mentioned - I am using different position for the icons followed by the panel title. Hence, in that case i am using `"v-slot:actions="{ expanded }"`. I hope it will clear the requirement to you.

Comment: in your Playground i moved your icons in template and worked,  `<template v-slot:actions="{ expanded }">
<v-icon v-if="expanded">mdi-chevron-up</v-icon><v-icon v-else>mdi-chevron-down</v-icon> </template>`, Please do this and let me know the result.

Comment: I put the picture in my post for you.

Comment: As per my requirement, I want to use those icons in front of the panel title but as per your screenshot, you added those icons at the end of panel.